# How do I create my own custom command line script in zsh?

Tags: command-line, scripting, zsh

I want to be able to run simple one line commands on my terminal, but instead of them being complicated I want them to be very simple, writing my own commands for these complex command lines that I have to write out so frequently. I am using the zsh command line and for example I would want to do this.

```
% npx tailwindcss -i ./static/styles.css -o ./static/output.css --watch
```

into something much easier to read such as

```
% build tailwindcss
```

Another problem/example is where if I would like to use http-server, but I want to turn off the caching, I don't think you can change the default settings for http-server module to turn off the caching, I have to do this:

```
% http-server -c-1
```

I know it is not too much of a big deal but I would like to at least pretend that the zero caching is the default. So I could do something like this with the command line:

```
% run server
```

And that would just run the server.

Also as a side note if this is not the best command line tool to do stuff like this in like maybe bash would be better I would be open to using a different command line tool as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using aliases

If you run the exact same command every time you could alias it like this:

```bash
alias http-server="http-server -c-1"
alias <alias-name>="npx tailwindcss -i ./static/styles.css -o ./static/output.css --watch"
```

Now `http-server` expands to `http-server -c-1` and `<alias-name>` expands to `npx tailwindcss -i ./static/styles.css -o ./static/output.css --watch`

### Using functions

If you want to choose the input file each time you could write a function instead:

```bash
build(){
    npx tailwindcss -i $1 -o ./static/output.css --watch
}
```

Then you can build with `build file.css`

Add the alias or function to ~/.zshrc if you want it available every time you start zsh

### Using bck-i-search

Use Ctrl+r to search history. Pressing Ctrl+r and writing "tailwind" will likely show you the full command. You can even comment the function with some arbitrary words to make them easier to find in history (e.g. "aaa")

```bash
npx tailwindcss -i ./static/styles.css -o ./static/output.css --watch #aaa
```

Comment: Wow I don't know why I didn't know about this before, cheers!